# Progress bar control......between two dialog

Tags: multithreading, mfc, modal-dialog

My application is based on serial communication.
It has main dialog window, from this we can select three options pump,crind and kiosk.
When i choose any one say pump, then small dialog is called (CommonResponse)with progress bar and getting time of pump from command files.This small window is on separate thread created as worker thred.
Now i want this small window with progress bar is on main thread but in background serial communication should be going on......How to do and steps for doing this?

One option for doing this is instead of progress bar, serial communication is on separate thread.But it is very time consuming process now because all things are ready only this part we want to change....
Thank you in advnce!!!

Comment: Do I understand that you want a window in a worker thread? Bad idea. Except under very, very rare circumstances, which doesn't seem to be your case, all GUI interactions should be in the main thread. Then any worker threads communicate with it via messages and the main thread updates the GUI, like xMRi says in an answer. Check [this link](http://www.flounder.com/workerthreads.htm) to see how to do it, explanations on why worker threads must not touch the GUI, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a handle to your main thread window to the background thread.

Use PostMessaage to send a private message that informs the main thread about the progress. The main thread can decode it and set the embedded progress bar to the value you want and need.